# WiFi driver keeps restoring after delete

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver

I have an issue with wifi on laptop Dell N5110 Windows 10x64 clean install (Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter). WIfi goes "no internet" every 5 minutes. Other devices have no problems with this router.
What I treid to do:

- reset via NETSH
- check power management
- choose channel number manually
- remove WiFi driver, ethernet driver via control panel
- remove WiFi driver via Device manager
- use pnputil

none of this worked, but intresting that removal of drivers via Control panel had no effect - wifi worked like nothing happened. I tried to remove driver via Device manager, scan for changes and driver is on it's old place again instantly like nothing happened. Please help to remove driver completely to install again.

Comment: When you do the clean install are you removing your partitions before you install Windows?

Comment: yes. does this matter? problem appeared only recently, had no problems earlier.

Comment: If you are going to push back, and require me to explain every question I have, I just attempt to help somebody else.  Why can’t you just select the correct driver you want manually within Device Manager?

Comment: select where? it is shown as correct and as it works perfectly. I can't event delete this to install something else.

Comment: You don’t have to delete the driver to select a different driver, I assumed you have a device driver you want to use, if your attempting to delete the existing driver.

Comment: @Ramhound I have only one driver, that I already have installed. It's the same, just wanted to reinstall.

Comment: If it’s already installed, what’s the point, of reinstalling it?

Comment: because I have problems with WiFi, want to try reinstalling.

Comment: You should be able to extract the .inf file from the driver installer, that will allow you to manually select the driver, but honestly, I believe you are barking up the wrong tree.  Installing the exact same driver you already have installed, even if you remove the file first, isn't going to resolve your problem.

Comment: @ramhound totally agree here. Update the driver, if you keep experiencing the issue replace the wlan card. The chipsets on these cards do (rare but happens) burn-out/malfunction. Broadcom especially if you jack up the tx power through the driver.

Comment: @Ramhound gentlemen, one does not use 2013 year driver because he like it, but because there is nothing newer for one's aging laptop. Now I have manually chosen 2012 driver. We shall see.

Comment: @usersample You didn’t tell us the date of the driver, you indicate you wanted to install the SAME, driver.  I asked you to select the driver manually for that reason because I suspected you wanted to select a different version of the driver but you never specifically indicated that despite multiple attempts from me asking for specifics

Comment: @Ramhound well, initially I indeed wanted install exactly the same driver, because it works sometimes. 2012 driver seems to work normally so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen 2012 driver instead of 2013 in Computer Management - Device Manager - Network adapters - Broadcom Network Adapter - Properties - Driver - Update driver - Browser my computer - Let me pick from a list - Uncheck Show compatible software - Choose broadcom driver with the same name but lower version - Reboot. Everything seems to work fine so far. Hope it may help someone eventually.